# Guardar en archivo.txt el numero de intentos de inicio de sesión

Tags: php

tengo un inicio de sesión donde el usuario ya esta introducido en el código,
y quiero crear dos ficheros, uno usr.txt (donde me guardara el usuario y contraseña) y otro con nombre registro.txt donde quiero guardar el numero de intentos incorrectos de inicio de sesión.
Es en el segundo fichero de registro.txt donde me quedado atascado..

```
    <?php
    if (($_POST["NUsuario"]=="admin") && ($_POST["UPass"]=="1234")){
        SESSION_START();

        $_SESSION["autentificado"] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION["nombre"] = $_POST["NUsuario"];

        header("Location: archivo-protegido.php");

    }else{


        // Lo abro para leerlo
         $fileOpen = fopen("registro.txt", "r");



         header("Location: index.php?error=si");

    }



    $usuario = $_POST['NUsuario'];
    $password = $_POST['UPass'];


    // Abro el archivo
    $file = fopen("usr.txt", "w");

    // Le cargo los datos
    fwrite($file, "$usuario" . PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($file, "$password" . PHP_EOL);

    // Lo cierro
    fclose($file);


    fclose($fileOpen);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver que te parece así:

Cada vez que falla el logueo voy acumulando intentos en el contador, debo  iniciar la sesión para poder hacer esto.

Después, en el momento del logueo correcto, guardo lo acumulado junto con el resto de datos.

```
    <?php
    SESSION_START();

    if (($_POST["NUsuario"]=="admin") && ($_POST["UPass"]=="1234")){

        $_SESSION["autentificado"] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION["nombre"] = $_POST["NUsuario"];

        $usuario = $_POST['NUsuario'];
        $password = $_POST['UPass'];
        $intentos = intval($_SESSION["intentos"]);
        unset($_SESSION["intentos"]);

        // Abro y guardo
        $file = fopen("registro.txt", "w");
        fwrite($file, "urs: $usuario  psw: $password  incorrectos: $intentos" . PHP_EOL);
        fclose($file);


        header("Location: archivo-protegido.php");

    }else{
        SESSION_START();

        if (isset($_SESSION["intentos"])) {
            $_SESSION["intentos"] = $_SESSION["intentos"] + 1;
        } else {
            $_SESSION["intentos"] = 1;            
        }

        header("Location: index.php?error=si");

    }



    $usuario = $_POST['NUsuario'];
    $password = $_POST['UPass'];


    // Abro el archivo
    $file = fopen("usr.txt", "w");

    // Le cargo los datos
    fwrite($file, "$usuario" . PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($file, "$password" . PHP_EOL);

    // Lo cierro
    fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: El modo de apertura del fichero debería ser "a" pues con "w" se truncaran los valores anteriores. http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php